# add custom metadata namespace in CQ DAM

Tags: adobe, aem, sling, crx, dam

I'm trying to add custom metadata namespace to CQ DAM.
I. e. URI `http://example.com/` with prefix `ex`

- added namespace in /crx/explorer/nodetypes/index.jsp in Namespaces tab
- added line `<ex = 'http://example.com/'>` in `/libs/dam/nodetypes/dam.cnd`
- created `/libs/dam/options/metadata/ex` folder

then I can't set `metadata` property to the `/libs/dam/options/metadata/ex` folder, nor add any subnode to it. ("No matching property definition found" error).

What is the full procedure of adding custom metadata namespace in CQ DAM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Two first steps are alternative ways of doing the same thing.
- The created `/libs/dam/options/metadata/ex` folder should by
  `sling:Folder` not `nt:Folder`